# NLog doesnt work on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, nlog

I have asp.net core 1.1 app, which is running on Ubuntu 16.04. Logging is configured using NLog:

```
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    loggerFactory.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
    app.AddNLogWeb();
```

On my dev Windows system everything is working fine: log folder created and logging is working as expected. But on Linux logging doesnt work. What is wrong?

nlog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Warn"
      internalLogFile="internal-nlog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="logs/${shortdate}" />
  <variable name="logRootDirectory" value="logs" />

  <targets>
    <target name="fileLogTrace" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/trace.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogDebug" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/debug.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogInfo" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/info.txt" />
    <target name="fileLogWarn" xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/warn.txt" />
   </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" level="Trace" writeTo="fileLogTrace" />
    <logger name="*" level="Debug" writeTo="fileLogDebug" />
    <logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="fileLogInfo" />
    <logger name="*" level="Warn" writeTo="fileLogWarn" />
  </rules>

</nlog>
```

Comment: What version of NLog? Do you have permission to write files in the folder? Have you checked the internal-nlog.txt ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen
NLog 5.0 beta
Yes all permissions
I couldnt find this file even on Windows. Where should it be placed? In the app root folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally solved issue.
There were some problems with permissions. Several `$ sudo chmod -R 777 .` and several sever restarts do the trick. Everything is logging now.

Comment: Careful! 777 is a potentially dangerous permission, especially when you're doing it recursively. Better to check the user/group of the process that needs to write to the files/directories and modify your permissions accordingly.